# Tracing slow running query "Invalid amount of bind variables"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, opscenter

I'm trying to trace some slow running queries on my cluster in OpsCenter 5.2.1, DSE 4.8.10.

Every query that I try to trace in opscenter performance service gives the same error: `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Invalid amount of bind variables`

For example, `SELECT trans_id FROM trans_summary WHERE brand_id = ? AND shard_id = ? AND yearmonth = 1510`

The PRIMARY KEY for that table is `PRIMARY KEY ((brand_id, yearmonth, shard_id), trans_id)`, so I'm not sure if I'm not understanding opscenter or the query is wrong.

Comment: For the CQL query you've shown (`SELECT trans_id FROM trans_summary WHERE brand_id = ? AND shard_id = ? AND yearmonth = 1510`), can you include the source code snippet which is making that request through the Java driver? That's probably where the mismatch of number of variables is happening.

Comment: LHWizard, was this ever resolved?